# Make ReadyBoost cache more aggressively

Tags: performance, cache, readyboost, performance-tuning

I have always had a 32GB high-speed Transcend SD card in my laptop for ReadyBoost, but it isn't very helpful because Windows isn't making heavy use of it: the cache size is usually 2 GB or less and cache reads are few and far apart.  My laptop has a slow 5400 RPM hard drive, so I/O is almost always the bottleneck when it comes to performance on my system (8 GB of memory is installed).

Is there a way I can adjust ReadyBoost so that it caches more aggressively, so that it can have a more significant impact on performance?

Comment: If Windows is not using ReadyBoost then Windows has determine that using it wouldn't provide a huge increase in performance.  You don't indicate how much memory you have.

Comment: @Ramhound: The system has 8 GB of memory, the maximum supported.  On average, 3 to 4.5 GB of memory is in use

Comment: You do understand your system will use your system memory before needing or using ReadyBoost storage right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReadyBoost is not designed for this type of usage.  ReadyBoost is designed for *low-memory* machines, which your machine is not. Your computer simply has to much memory and cache to gain any improvements from ReadyBoost.

ReadyBoost provides the most significant performance improvement under the following circumstances:

- The computer has a slow hard disk drive. Computers with a primary hard disk Windows Experience Index (WEI) subscore lower than 4.0 will see the most significant improvements.
- The flash storage provides fast, random, non-sequential reads. Sequential read speed is less important.
- The flash storage is connected by a fast bus. Typically, USB memory card readers are not sufficiently fast. However, connecting flash memory to an internal memory card reader might provide sufficient performance.

See this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff356869.aspx).